# MySQL: Сложение строк

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Понадобилось сложение строки одного столбца в зависимости от даты.В итоге написал такое:

```
SELECT 
    sum(_Fld19180) as [SumID],
    _Fld19184 As [UserNameID],
    _Description As [GeneralOperationID],
    convert(date,_Fld19178,112)
FROM rlt17.dbo._InfoRg19176
INNER JOIN rlt17.dbo._Reference144 on rlt17.dbo._InfoRg19176._Fld19177RRef = rlt17.dbo._Reference144._IDRRef
GROUP BY _Fld19178,_Description,_Fld19184
```

При этом результате просто выводятся все операции и сколько на них тратится времени, сложение не происходит. Где я думаю неправильно?

Comment: GROUP BY должен полностью повторять поля ! т.е. GROUP BY _Fld19178,_Description,convert(date,_Fld19178,112)

Comment: @santavital , спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: @santavital впишите ответом, нечего стесняться.

Comment: @santavital , да не хотел ваш ответ воровать, ждал потому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` должен полностью повторять поля ! т.е. `GROUP BY _Fld19178,_Description,convert(date,_Fld19178,112)`